# How can i submit my form in php to echo a response?

Tags: php, forms, echo, submit

I'm trying to make a form with radio checkboxes and a textbox. The goal is to receive what is set in the radio buttons/the textbox and echo it (For now). The future goal is to upload it to MySQL, but that wont be a problem.

**EDIT: i forgot to set the method="post" that solved the problem**

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo '<div class="error infonachricht">'
        .'<center>Aktuell liegt ein Beurlaubungsantrag von '
        .$beurlauber.' vom '.$startdate.' bis zum '.$enddate.' vor:<br><br>"'
        .$begruendung
        .'"<form>Annahme:<br>'.
        '<input type="radio" name="annahme'.$i.'" value="Ja">Ja<br>
        <input type="radio" name="annahme'.$i.'" value="Nein">Nein<br>
        Neuer Grund: '.'<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" name="grund"><br>  <br>
        <input type="submit" name="clicked'.$i.'" value="Absenden">'.
        '</form>';
if (isset($_POST['clicked'.$i])){
    if (isset ($_POST['annahme'.$i])){
        if ($_POST['annahme'.$i]=="Ja"){
            echo "Ja";
        }
        if ($_POST['annahme'.$i]=="Nein"){
            echo "Nein";
        }
    }
}

echo '</center></div>';
echo "</tr>";
```

I expected it to show either "Ja" or "Nein", but it didn't show anything at all.

Comment: did you dump your post array?

Comment: and what's in `$i`?

Comment: Your form tag is just `<form>`, and the default method is `GET` not `POST`. So if you want to use `$_POST` you need to change your tag to `<form method="post">`

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: You are generating invalid HTML. A `<div>` can't be a child of ` <tr>` and the `<center>` element is obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

when you create a form in html it should have a method. So if you add method="POST" in your  tag, it should be work as a post form.

Also i recommend you to change your inputs to a `<option>` tag. You can edit with css if you want some buttons. Your form should be looking like that;

```
 <form method="POST" action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="annahme">
    <option value="ja">Ja</option>
    <option value="nein">Nein</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: "when you create a form in html it should have a method" — The method attribute is optional. In this case, the server side code expects a POST request so it is needed, but it is not required in the general case.

Comment: "Also i recommend you to change your inputs to a `<option>` tag. " — Why? Dropdown menus are useful if you have a lot of options, but radio buttons let the user see all the options without having to click to make the menu appear. For short lists, they are the better choice.